# Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to get this code to work, I'm not brilliant at JS but I cant see anything that could be causing this.

This is my code

javascript:

```
function end(){
    c='798|209';
    var d = document;

    if (window.frames.length > 0)
        d = window.main.document;

    url = d.URL;

    if (url.indexOf('screen=place') == -1)
        alert('This script needs to be run from the rally point');

    a = c.match(/(\d+\|\d+)/g);
    b = a[Math.round(Math.random()*(a.length-1))].split("|");
    d.forms[0].x.value = b[0];
    d.forms[0].y.value = b[1];
    d.forms[0].spear.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].sword.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].axe.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].spy.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].light.value = 529;
    d.forms[0].heavy.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].ram.value = 1;
    d.forms[0].catapult.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].snob.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].archer.value = 0;
    d.forms[0].marcher.value = 100;
    d.forms[0].knight.value = 0;
}

end();
```

Comment: `window.main` is probably undefined, who knows? Are you sure it should'nt be `window.top` ??

Comment: What makes you think `window.main` should exist?

Comment: Looking at other examples window.main was used a lot! apart from that nothing :S

Comment: I guess it's a global they define. It doesn't exist by-def in javascript.

Comment: Its run via a bookmark in the browser

Comment: @bažmegakapa hopefully this doesn't indicate this is the body of a `href` attribute (or an `onX` attribute; I've seen people put `javascript:` there :-( )

Comment: @OllyStredwick you can't assume something exists if a browser (or the page, if your scriptlet is site-locked) doesn't offer that. Mine doesn't here.

Comment: Where are these "`other examples`"?

Comment: What is the site you're developing for?

Comment: Its a tribal wars script. @Jan Dvorak

Comment: @OllyStredwick does that mean that we are unable to answer wihout a registration? The best we can say is "`window.main` doesn't exist".

Comment: @Olly Stredwick glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
window.main.document
```

to

```
window.parent.document
```